# Finding the limit of $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{10^x} \frac{1-e^{it}}{1-e^{\frac{t}{10}x}}=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, limits

Finding the limit of $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{10^x} \frac{1-e^{it}}{1-e^{\frac{ti}{10}x}}=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$$

To me it looks like this limit should be 0. I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: from where is problem and for what stand the variables?

Comment: There is an $i$ missing in the exponent on the exponential function in the denominator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1-e^{it}}{10^x\left(1-e^{\frac{it}{10^x}}\right)}&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1-e^{it}}{10^x \left(1-\left(1+\frac{it}{10^x}+O\left(\frac{1}{10^x}\right)^2\right)\right)}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1-e^{it}}{-it+O\left(\frac{1}{10^x}\right)}\\\\
&=-\frac{1-e^{it}}{it}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sure.  $e^z=1+z+O(z^2)$.  Now, let $z=it/10^x$.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.